# About luggage details in Doha airport

Tags: luggage, doha

I am travelling from Berlin to trivandrum in qatar airways and i have 1 day tranait in doha.  Do i need to collect the luggage from doha or it directly goes to next flight?

Answer (score 2):

It directly goes on to the destination as long as it’s a single booking and your stop is just a transit stopover, i.e. not booked as a destination on a multi city booking.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that any stop for less than 24 hours is a transit, and your bags will be transferred automatically.